# psutil.virtual_memory Not Callable

Tags: python, memory, psutil

I'm making a function in python that returns memory usage percentage, and I'm using psutil.

When I tried to run print(psutil.virtual_memory().percent()) I got an error that int object is not callable.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```py
mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
mem = mem.percent()
print("RAM: " + str(mem) + "%")
```

I'm expecting it to return a percentage instead of an error.

Answer (score 1):

According to [[ReadTheDocs.psutil]: psutil.**virtual_memory**()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Return statistics about system memory usage **as a named tuple** including the following fields, expressed in bytes.

So, you must **not call** `mem.percent()`.

Example:

> ```py
> >>> import psutil
> >>>
> >>> mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
> >>> mem
> svmem(total=34190491648, available=14239588352, percent=58.4, used=19950903296, free=14239588352)
> >>>
> >>> mem.percent
> 58.4
> ```